# How does an element choose which corner to shrink into on window resize?

Tags: css, resize

When I resize the browser window, an image shrinks (as it should) but shrinks up and to the leftt within its div. What determines which direction it shrinks in, and can I choose?

Example is live here: http://cdpn.io/FdIKv
 (shrink page to see)

Bonus for how to make text shrink instead of overlapping/being overlapped.

Thanks!

edit: apologies, here is the code:

```
<style type="text/css">
#logo-div {
    max-width: 24%;
    width: 24%;
    height: auto;
    clear: both;
    z-index: 0;
    float: right;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#site-logo {
    max-width: 100%;
   display : block;
   margin : 0 auto;
    }


#site-title a {
    color: #CB2027;
    font-size: 2.7em;
    margin-right: auto;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#site-title {
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 80%;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#site-description {
    color: #000000;
    font-size: 2.340em;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 76%;

}

#branding hgroup {
    max-width: 60%;
float: left;
width: 60%;
}

</style>
<header id="branding" role="banner">
<!--<div id="logo-and-hgroup">-->
<div id="logo-div"><img id="site-logo" src="http://farm6.staticflickr.com/5016/5421726832_eb5c0e25fc_m.jpg" alt="" /> </div>
    <hgroup>

<h1 id="site-title">
<a href="http://google.com/" title="Thisisone ATest" rel="home">Thisisone ATest</a>
</h1>
                <h2 id="site-description">This is where the description will go</h2>



            </hgroup>
```

Comment: You need to post your problem code as well as a your link to the your site/jsfiddle/etc. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/84342/answer-that-only-contains-a-link-to-jsfiddle

Comment: The image is not shrinking in ANY direction.  It is merely shirking based on the width of its parent element.  The image keeps its aspect ratio (meaning the height shrinks in proportion to its width).  Your question is not very well defined.  Please include your problem code and tell us what issues you are having.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't explain very well. When the image shrinks its centre moves towards the upper left, and so it 'sticks' to the top and thus moves 'away' from the bottom of the page. Effectively it is 'anchored' to the top.

Comment: It actually sticks to the upper right, that is because its parent element "#logo-div" is "float:right".  The image will always stick to the right as defined by its parent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything will shrink towards the top left *by default*. Shrinking towards the top is due to the fact that most human writing system runs from top downwards — it's an accepted universal convention. Left-to-right is more contentious — there are many right-to-left digital writing formats (Arabic, for example), and can be specified with CSS `{direction: rtl}` or HTML attribute `dir="rtl"`.

So by default, all content starts at the top left, extends towards the right, and returns to the next available space below when that isn't available. A `display: block` element (like a `div`) will, by default, occupy the full width available to it — meaning that, without any extra CSS, the following contents will appear below it.

However, your code specifies that `#logo-div`, which contains your image `#site-logo`, should `float: right` — meaning it will hug the right-hand-edge of its container (the `#branding` header, which as discussed occupies full available width). By default, floated elements shrink their width to fit their contents, but it also has a width set to a percentage, meaning it will shrink or expand based on that available width.

You can't `float` up or down — only left and right — but you can use `position: absolute` to define `bottom: 0`, which would force its bottom edge to match the bottom edge of the nearest relatively positioned ancestor (the viewport, in this case). But, just as when you specify a float, a block will ignore it's natural full-width, downward sequence position, absolute positioning means float is ignored (you can also set left and right values, though).

Created [a demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qyGtf) for you with some of these properties applied to explore the difference.

Comment: That's hugely helpful! Thanks very much Barney, makes sense to me now.

Comment: As an aside, is it possible to make that text shrink instead of wrapping?

Comment: Afraid not! Text rendering is its own weird thing, and hinges on `font-size`. Natively, you can arbitrarily `transform` elements (using the `zoom` shorthand), but whatever you specify there will be in relation to the already computed element dimensions (whatever they may be based on the rest of the CSS) — [more on this here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/transform). Besides, that's the element containing the text, and the text only shrinks as a result. There are some Javascript libraries for this though: [FitText](fittextjs.com) will modify font-size to fill container width.

Comment: Thanks very much Barney, I'll look into that. You've made my day much easier!